# How do you refer to nested types using generics in Java?

Tags: java, generics

How do you create a generic class that refers to nested generic types?

I'm trying to create a Comparator class which can compare the inner types of B without wanting to expose what those types are. In the following example I get a compiler warning for raw casting my T inner nested values to Comparable:

```
public class SSCCE {

    // Compare my A instances.
    class AComparator<T extends B> implements Comparator<T> {

        @Override
        public int compare(final T o1, final T o2) {
            return o1.getValue().compareTo(o2.getValue());
        }
    }


    class A extends B<Integer> {
        @Override Integer getValue() { return 1; }
    }

    class A2 extends B<String> {
        @Override String getValue() { return "Test String!"; }
    }

    abstract class B<T extends Comparable<T>> {
        abstract T getValue();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SSCCE sscce = new SSCCE();
        AComparator<A> comparator = sscce.new AComparator<>();
        comparator.compare(sscce.new A(), sscce.new A());
    }
}
```

Is it possible to represent the inner values using to safely allow casting?

Things I've tried:

- Creating a wildcard comparable (uncompilable) :

  ```
  class AComparator2<T extends B<? extends Comparable<?>>> implements Comparator<T> {

      @Override
      public int compare(final T o1, final T o2) {
          Comparable<?> o1value = (Comparable) o1.getValue();
          Comparable<?> o2value = (Comparable) o2.getValue();
          return o1value.compareTo(o2value);
      }
  }
  ```
- Declaring a secondary generic parameter type (U), which simply postpones the problem:

  ```
  class AComparator3<T extends B<U>, U extends Comparable<U>> implements Comparator<T> {

      @Override
      public int compare(final T o1, final T o2) {
          U o1value = o1.getValue();
          U o2value = o2.getValue();
          return o1value.compareTo(o2value);
      }
  }
  ...
  AComparator3<A, Comparable<U>> comparator = sscce.new AComparator3();
  ```

This comparator isn't to compare two instances of the classes A, rather part of their contents.

Comment: `AComparator3<A,Integer> comparator = sscce.new AComparator3<A,Integer>();` works fine for your second solution

Comment: It does but _if possible_ I don't want to rely on exposing the inner types. I don't expect the dev to know what they are.

Comment: Do you want to create comparator for inner classes like `AComparator<A>` or are you also interested in alternative solution which needs only comparable type like `AComparator<Integer>`?

Comment: Nested generics... ***shudder***

Comment: Well, I'm more shuddering for *recursive* generics...so I'll unshudder.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The wildcard solution does not work

```
    class AComparator2<T extends B<?>> {
        public int compare(T o1, T o2)
```

because `T` is too loose here; we can't make sure two `T`'s can compare to each other -- it's possible that `o1` is a `B<X1>` and `o2` is a `B<X2>`, and `X1, X2` are two different types.

Your 3rd solution restricts `T` to a specific `B<U>`

```
    class AComparator3<T extends B<U>, U extends Comparable<U>>
```

this works perfectly; except that the use site has to specify `U`, even though `U` is deducible from `T`.

```
    AComparator3<A, Integer>  
                    ^^^^^^^ duh!
```

This is annoying. The same problem has been asked before from other use cases. No good answers.

Fortunately, in your case, `U` isn't needed anywhere on use site, therefore we could simply use a wildcard for it

```
    AComparator3<A, ?> comparator = sscce.new AComparator3<>();
    comparator.compare(sscce.new A(), sscce.new A());
```

In fact, the comparator is a `Comparator<A>`, which is probably all you need. Also we can create a convenience method to hide the ugliness of `new`. So you may do something like

```
    Comparator<A> comparator = sscce.comparator();
```

Comment: or just `Comparator<A> comparator = sscce.new AComparator3<>();`

Comment: Great answer. I'll accept it once I've had a chance to test it.

Comment: The above code gives a compiler error for the lines:
`AComparator3<A, ?> comparator = sscce.new AComparator3<>();`
and
`Comparator<A> comparator2 = sscce.new AComparator3<>();`

Error is: `Cannot infer type arguments for AComparator3<>`

Did you run into any similar issues?

Comment: Well I'll be damned. The issue I'm having is based on the fact that I'm using Java 7. Type inference just doesn't know how to associate the comparator as it cannot infer the types.

Comment: @Creperum - bummers:) In that case, I would rather use the raw types; just suppress the warnings.

Comment: @bayou.io That's a good point. It would only need to be temporary and can be refactored in JDK8. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Have you consider Java 8 solution?

```
 Comparator<A> comparator = ((t1,t2)-> t1.getValue().compareTo(t1.getValue()));
  comparator.compare(sscce.new A(), sscce.new A());
```

Comment: Locked into JDK 7 (unfortunately!)

Comment: It would make more sense to say `Comparator<B<Integer>> c1=Comparator.comparing(B::getValue);` as the goal was to create a comparator which is *not* exposing `A` (though it is capable of comparing `A`s).

Comment: @Holger i believe OP didn't want to expose inner type not A

Comment: hmm... if the logic is simply enough, we could write lambda directly and explicitly, not relying on another API. e.g. `identityFunc = x->x;`

Comment: `A` *is* an inner type. Which inner type do you think does the OP refer to?

Comment: @bayou.io: look, this “simple” lambda expression is already complex enough to be broken as it is calling `getValue()` on `t1` twice instead of `t1` and `t2`. By using `comparing(B::getValue)`, you are immune against such mistakes. Besides that, `Comparator.comparing` stems from the API that is unavoidable when you are implementing a `Comparator`…

Comment: @Holger - right. OP probably wants (we are all guessing here) `Comparator<A> c1=Comparator.comparing(A::getValue)`

Answer (score 3):

You may be interested in comparator which should compare types extending B but only if they hold same comparable type. Such comparator may look like

```
class AComparator<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Comparator<B<T>> {
    @Override
    public int compare(final B<T> o1, final B<T> o2) {
        return o1.getValue().compareTo(o2.getValue());
    }
}
```

and you can use it like

```
AComparator<Integer> comparator = sscce.new AComparator<>();
comparator.compare(sscce.new A(), sscce.new A());
comparator.compare(sscce.new A(), sscce.new A2());//compilation error
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things you have to change to achieve what you want, which I believe if just implement a Generic [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).

First, AComparator should look like:

```
// Compare my A instances.
class AComparator<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Comparator<T> {

    @Override
    public int compare(final T o1, final T o2) {
        return o1.compareTo(o2);
    }
}
```

You don't need your class B, since A and A2 will implement [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) directly. Just delete it.

Your A and A2 classes:

```
class A implements Comparable<A> {
    @Override public int compareTo(A other) {
        // your compare logic here
        // return negative if less than, 0 if equal, positive if greater than
    }
}

class A2 implements Comparable<A2> {
    @Override public int compareTo(A2 other) {
        // your compare logic here
        // return negative if less than, 0 if equal, positive if greater than
    }
}
```

It is important that you read the documentation for [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html), to understand what is expected from the returned value.

Does that makes sense?

PS: I didn't test those codes, they are just out of my head.

Comment: Sorry I didn't make it clear in the question: I'm after a comparator that is comparing the contents of these instances.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to have B implement Comparable directly, since you are using getValue() to do the compare. The below gets rid of the warning:

```
import java.util.Comparator;

public class SSCCE {
   class A extends B<Integer> {
      @Override Integer getValue() { return 1; }
   }

   class A2 extends B<String> {
      @Override String getValue() { return "Test String!"; }
   }

   abstract class B<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Comparable<B<T>>{
      abstract T getValue();

      @Override
      public int compareTo(B<T> other)
      {
         return getValue().compareTo(other.getValue());
      }
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SSCCE sscce = new SSCCE();
      Comparator.naturalOrder().compare(sscce.new A(), sscce.new A());
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is what you want:

```
public class SSCCE {

    static class BComparator<E extends Comparable<E>> implements Comparator<B<E>> {

        @Override
        public int compare(final B<E> o1, final B<E> o2) {
            return o1.getValue().compareTo(o2.getValue());
        }
    }

    static class A extends B<Integer> {
        @Override Integer getValue() { return 1; }
    }

    static class A2 extends B<String> {
        @Override String getValue() { return "Test String!"; }
    }

    static abstract class B<T extends Comparable<T>> {
        abstract T getValue();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SSCCE sscce = new SSCCE();
        BComparator<Integer> comparator = new BComparator<>();
        comparator.compare(new A(), new A());

        BComparator<String> comparator2 = new BComparator<>();
        comparator2.compare(new A2(), new A2());
    }
}
```

If you don't want your comparator to be able to compare instances of two different subclasses of B (like `A2 extends B<String>` and `A3 extends B<String>`), the following works:

```
public class SSCCE {

    static class BComparator<E extends Comparable<E>, T extends B<E>> implements Comparator<T> {

        @Override
        public int compare(final T o1, final T o2) {
            return o1.getValue().compareTo(o2.getValue());
        }
    }

    static class A extends B<Integer> {
        @Override Integer getValue() { return 1; }
    }

    static class A2 extends B<String> {
        @Override String getValue() { return "Test String!"; }
    }

    static abstract class B<T extends Comparable<T>> {
        abstract T getValue();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SSCCE sscce = new SSCCE();
        BComparator<Integer, A> comparator = new BComparator<>();
        comparator.compare(new A(), new A());

        BComparator<String, A2> comparator2 = new BComparator<>();
        comparator2.compare(new A2(), new A2());
    }
}
```